# Flutter: Screen remains white in real device but works good in emulator

Tags: android, flutter

I am developing a mobile application for android devices using flutter.

Everything looks good in emulator but debugging on real device shows white screen only. Configuration of both the devices real device and emulator are same.

I have tested it with more than 5 emulators of different android OS version and 4 real devices of difference OS versions.
App is running good in every emulator but on in any real device.

This is my code :

```
 import 'dart:convert';
 
 import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
 import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
 import 'package:news/API/WebAPI.dart';
 import 'package:news/Animation/FadeAnimation.dart';
 import 'package:news/Helper/DBHelper.dart';
 import 'package:news/Models/UserDetail.dart';
 import 'package:news/Pages/MasterPage.dart';
 import 'package:news/Widgets/Dialogs.dart';
 
 class AdminLogin extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _AdminLoginState createState() => _AdminLoginState();
 }
 
 class _AdminLoginState extends State<AdminLogin> {
   final GlobalKey<State> _keyLoader = new GlobalKey<State>();
   Logger log = new Logger();
   DBHelper db = new DBHelper();
   int Emp_ID = 0;
   String Emp_Name;
   String Head_Office_Name;
   int Head_Office_Code;
   UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();
   int User_ID=0;
   final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 
   final mobileController = TextEditingController();
   final passwordController = TextEditingController();
 
   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
 
     getUserDetails();
   }
 
 
   getUserDetails() async
   {
     UserDetail ob=await db.getUserDetails();
     setState(() {
       userDetail=ob;
       User_ID = userDetail.user_id;
     });
 
     if(User_ID>0)
       Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MasterPage()));
 
   }
 
 
   getAdminLogin() async {
     Dialogs.showLoadingDialog(context, _keyLoader);
 
     GetAdminLogin newsObject = GetAdminLogin(
         Password: passwordController.text, UserID: mobileController.text);
     await newsObject.getAdminLogin();
     setState(() {
       Emp_ID = newsObject.Emp_ID;
       Emp_Name = newsObject.Emp_Name;
       Head_Office_Code = newsObject.Head_Office_Code;
       Head_Office_Name = newsObject.Head_Office_Name;
 
 
     });
     Navigator.of(_keyLoader.currentContext, rootNavigator: true).pop();
 
     if (Emp_ID != 0) {
       db.insertUserDetails(Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Head_Office_Code, Head_Office_Name,"");
 
       Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MasterPage()));
     } else {
       showDialog(
           context: context,
           builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                 title: Text("Fail"),
                 content: Text("Invalid login!"),
               ));
     }
   }
 
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       body: Form(
         key: _formKey,
         child: SingleChildScrollView(
           child: Column(
             children: [
               _header(),
               Padding(
                 padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                 child: Column(
                   children: [
                     FadeAnimation(
                         1.8,
                         Container(
                           padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                               color: Colors.white,
                               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                               boxShadow: [
                                 BoxShadow(
                                     color: Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .2),
                                     blurRadius: 20.0,
                                     offset: Offset(0, 10)),
                               ]),
                           child: Column(
                             children: [
                               _txtMobile(),
                               _txtPassword(),
                             ],
                           ),
                         )),
                     SizedBox(
                       height: 30,
                     ),
                     _submitButton(),
                     SizedBox(
                       height: 25,
                     ),
                     FadeAnimation(
                         1.5,
                         InkWell(
                           onTap: () {
                             Navigator.pop(context);
                           },
                           child: Text(
                             "Back to User Login",
                             style: TextStyle(
                                 fontSize: 17, color: Color(0xFFF17033)),
                           ),
                         ))
                   ],
                 ),
               )
             ],
           ),
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
 
   Widget _header() {
     return Container(
       height: 350,
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
           image: DecorationImage(
               image: AssetImage('assets/images/background.png'),
               fit: BoxFit.fill)),
       child: Stack(
         children: [
           Positioned(
             left: 30,
             width: 80,
             height: 180,
             child: FadeAnimation(
               1,
               Container(
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     image: DecorationImage(
                   image: AssetImage("assets/images/light-1.png"),
                 )),
               ),
             ),
           ),
           Positioned(
             left: 150,
             width: 80,
             height: 140,
             child: FadeAnimation(
               1.3,
               Container(
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     image: DecorationImage(
                   image: AssetImage("assets/images/light-2.png"),
                 )),
               ),
             ),
           ),
           Positioned(
             right: 60,
             top: 25,
             width: 80,
             height: 150,
             child: FadeAnimation(
               1.5,
               Container(
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     image: DecorationImage(
                   image: AssetImage("assets/images/clock.png"),
                 )),
               ),
             ),
           ),
           Positioned(
             child: FadeAnimation(
               1.6,
               Container(
                 margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                 child: Center(
                   child: Text(
                     "Login",
                     style: TextStyle(
                         color: Colors.white,
                         fontSize: 40,
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           )
         ],
       ),
     );
   }
 
   Widget _txtMobile() {
     return Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
           border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[100]))),
       child: TextFormField(
         keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
         controller: mobileController,
         inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(9)],
         decoration: InputDecoration(
           border: InputBorder.none,
           hintText: "MIS ID",
           hintStyle: TextStyle(
             color: Colors.grey[400],
           ),
         ),
         validator: (String value) {
           if (value.isEmpty) {
             return "Enter MIS ID";
           }
         },
       ),
     );
   }
 
   Widget _txtPassword() {
     return Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
       child: TextFormField(
         keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
         obscureText: true,
         inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(30)],
         controller: passwordController,
         decoration: InputDecoration(
           border: InputBorder.none,
           hintText: "Password",
           hintStyle: TextStyle(
             color: Colors.grey[400],
           ),
         ),
         validator: (String value) {
           if (value.isEmpty) {
             return "Enter password";
           }
         },
       ),
     );
   }
 
   Widget _submitButton() {
     return FadeAnimation(
       2,
       Container(
         height: 50,
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
           gradient: LinearGradient(
             colors: [
               Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, 1),
               Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .6),
             ],
           ),
         ),
         child: SizedBox(
           width: double.infinity,
           child: MaterialButton(
             onPressed: () {
               bool _isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
               if (_isValid)
 //
 //                            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
 //                                MaterialPageRoute(
 //                                    builder: (context) => MasterPage()));
                 getAdminLogin();
             },
             child: Text(
               "Login",
               style:
                   TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
 }
```

Please help me :-)

Comment: Please add a stacktrace (error messages) from the console. Otherwise it is really hard to find the error :D Also is the error appearing on the real device in Release & Debug mode ?

Comment: there is no error appearing.

Comment: This might be an error with your SingleChildScrollView and your Column. Test to wrap your Column in a Container with a given height. If this does not work maybe try to take all the widgets out of the page and re-add them step by step.